# Batch script to write a line in host file to block a website

Tags: batch, hosts

Batch script to write a line in host file to block a website

I will be sending this remotely.  I know how to do it on my PC manually, but I need the batch command to send remotely to block a website.

Please help

I have tried

```
@echo off

set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

echo 0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com >> %hostspath%

exit
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: "it doesnt work." What is the error message?

Comment: `find /?` - a utilty to check whether the "patch" has already been applied. Also google `errorlevel` and `if`.

Comment: Might possibly work, but this script needs to run with (local) administrative priviliges, otherwise ..../hosts is read-only and cannot be modified. Also, please clarify how you intend to execute the script on the remote host and if/how you intend to prevent multiple copies of the same line appearing in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is:

```
@echo off
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
echo 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com >> %hostspath%
echo 127.0.0.1 facebook.com >> %hostspath%
exit
```

without a **.txt** extension on the `hosts` file name.

Comment: I doubt that this is really the answer, but, since the OP declined to tell us what problem they were having, we’ll never know.

Answer (score -2):

You need the extension File

```
@echo off
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt
echo 0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com >> %hostspath%
exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is wrong.  The name of the `hosts` file is exactly that--without an extension.

Comment: Agreed: hosts doesn't sport a file extension.